# How to show the result value cosine similarity in certain recommendation system

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix) 
cosine_sim
```

```
# Membuat dataframe dari variabel cosine_sim dengan baris dan kolom berupa title kdrama
cosine_sim_df = pd.DataFrame(cosine_sim, index=data['Title'], columns=data['Title'])
print('Shape:', cosine_sim_df.shape)
 
# Melihat similarity matrix pada setiap title kdrama
cosine_sim_df.sample(5, axis=1).sample(10, axis=0)
```

```
def kdrama_recommendations(kdrama_title, similarity_data=cosine_sim_df, items=data[['Title', 'Overview']], k=5):


    index = similarity_data.loc[:,kdrama_title].to_numpy().argpartition(
        range(-1, -k, -1))
    
    # Mengambil data dengan similarity terbesar dari index yang ada
    closest = similarity_data.columns[index[-1:-(k+2):-1]]
    
    # Drop kdrama_title agar kdrama_title yang dicari tidak muncul dalam daftar rekomendasi
    closest = closest.drop(kdrama_title, errors='ignore')
    
    return pd.DataFrame(closest).merge(items).head(k)
```

i want to know the similarity beside overview column
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdeAF.png)

i tried add new column in items but i got the error

```
    # Drop kdrama_title agar kdrama_title yang dicari tidak muncul dalam daftar rekomendasi
    closest = closest.drop(kdrama_title, errors='ignore')

    items.loc[:, 'similarity'] = similarity_data
    
    return pd.DataFrame(closest).merge(items).head(k)
```

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 2>()
1 # Mendapatkan rekomendasi kdrama yang mirip dengan When the Camellia Blooms
----> 2 kdrama_recommendations('When the Camellia Blooms')

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _set_item_frame_value(self, key, value)
4123
4124         if len(value.columns) != 1:
-> 4125             raise ValueError(
4126                 "Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single "
4127                 f"column {key}"

ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column similarity`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).